# Showing items in GridView Vertically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GV in my webpage which is showing 10 items. Which means my page is horizontally BIG.
How can align my GV to fit into my page OR How can I make my GV Vertical in size.

Any help?

Comment: Is it necessary to use a gv? If not, you may consider using a formView. By using a formView you can define ItemTemplates and design the layout of an item vertically. Using a detailsView allows you to show one item vertically also but does show only one item per page. hth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS to apply an explicit width; it will force it to appear a specific way.  Or, you can try to use this to apply a scrollbar:

```
<div style="width:800px;overflow-x:auto;">
   <asp:GridView .. />
</div>
```

HTH.